# PHP - What is the default data type of any PHP variable?

Tags: php

PHP is loosely Typed Language but could someone tell me, What is the default data type of any PHP variable? What is its implicit data Type?

Comment: Variables in PHP do not have intrinsic types - a variable does not know in advance whether it will be used to store a number or a string of characters.

Comment: You answered by yourself: _PHP is loosely Typed Language_

Comment: I had the same thought that It depends on the value assigned, but still there must be some implicit data type...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP understands that PHP is a loosely typed language and therefore the type of any initialized variable is determined by the data it holds; so read that way, the question then becomes *What is the type of an uninitialized variable?* - the answer to which is `null`

PHP doesn't generally allow you to declare variables *without* initializing them, there's no direct equivalent to:

```
Dim SomeVar
```

Therefore the only way to *see* that "default" data type is to evaluate either a variable that hasn't been set or a class member that holds no data.

1: A variable that hasn't been set

```
echo $someVar === null ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL"; //outputs NULL (and triggers a Warning)
```

2: A declared class member that holds no data

```
class Test {
  public static $someVar;
}

var_dump(Test::$someVar); // outputs NULL
```

Therefore:

- the type of any initialized variable is determined by the data it holds
- the type of any uninitialized variable is `null`

Comment: The question asks "what is default type of ANY variable" which includes initialized variables. Now what?

Comment: it's not "still NULL" once it is initialized, unless you initialize it to NULL.

Comment: Then your definition of "initialized" and mine are different. For me, that is just a variable declaration which happens to have a default value. Initialization is assigning a value to it explicitly.

Comment: Reworded for clarity (hopefully)

Comment: Reworded again as I wasn't happy with the previous clarification :)

Answer (score 8):

PHP's variables are dynamic, and change depending on the data inside them. So they have no datatype by default.

Answer (score 5):

From the [manual on variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a
>   very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a default value of
>   their type depending on the context in which they are used - booleans
>   default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g.
>   used in echo) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an empty
>   array.

So, they are what you make of them.

Answer (score -1):

**Type Juggling**

PHP does not require (or support) explicit type definition in variable declaration; a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used. That is to say, if a string value is assigned to variable $var, $var becomes a string. If an integer value is then assigned to $var, it becomes an integer.

An example of PHP's automatic type conversion is the addition operator '+'. If either operand is a float, then both operands are evaluated as floats, and the result will be a float. Otherwise, the operands will be interpreted as integers, and the result will also be an integer. Note that this does not change the types of the operands themselves; the only change is in how the operands are evaluated and what the type of the expression itself is.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: so you mean NULL is the default Data Type?

Comment: As I understand it `null` is the default data type in about the same way that `undefined` is the default type in JavaScript. i.e. an uninitialised variable can be evaluated as `null`.