# PHP 7.1 void return types understanding

Tags: php

I have done some tests with the next minor Version of `PHP` (`7.1beta`).

During the tests with void return types I noticed that gettype returns `NULL` for a void method. Can anyone explain why it does that?

```
function returnVoid(): void {
    return;
}

echo gettype(returnVoid()); // returns "NULL"
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: *Is this the expected behavior?* : Probably : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142476/php-what-is-the-default-data-type-of-any-php-variable/13143336#13143336

Comment: void means "don't return anything". And in programming NULL is nothing (no value).

Comment: @CD001 Yes, this is fact in PHP prior v.7.1. But would it not be better to output "void" instead of "NULL" considering the new return type?

Comment: @Bert okay, makes sense. But why we have to use void instead of NULL as the return type? May be `function returnNothing(): null {}` not wiser?

Comment: Void isn't really a type though, it basically just denotes *no return expected* - but PHP "defaults" to `NULL` for any uninitialised variable.

Comment: @u-nik you're a bit late to the party. The proposal had been made to the PHP standards on `2015-10-14`. Check https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type where your question of why `void` and not `null` had been asked and answered

Comment: If I can recall correctly, maybe I am wrong, in Java i.e example, if you set return  void, it understands you do not want to return anything, so if you add a return, it will throw an exception. In Case of PHP 7 since return types are optional, NULL is a good return.